# I have created a Black Jack game in c # for one player. How can I create it for two or more players?

Tags: c#, blackjack

I have to alter this in order for more than one player to be available. Do I change something in the Player class? Or do I create a new class for all Players? I am on the right track? Here is the code so far:

```
namespace Blackjack
{
    class Program
    {
        static Player[] players = new Player[5];
        static int pointer = 0;

    class PlayingCard
    {
        public string Suit;
        public int Value;
        public int Points;

        // Alternate Constructor with 2 parameters - Int for Suit, Int for Value
        // We use this in the generateDeck() function
        public PlayingCard(int s, int v)
        {
            Value = v; // Sets the Value of the card to the value of v (The second argument)
            switch (s) // Case statement based on the value of s
            {
                case 1: // If s == 1, then set the Suit to Clubs
                    Suit = "♣";
                    break;
                case 2: // If s == 2, then set the Suit to Diamonds
                    Suit = "♦";
                    break;
                case 3: // If s == 3, then set the Suit to Hearts
                    Suit = "♥";
                    break;
                case 4: // If s == 4, then set the Suit to Spades
                    Suit = "♠";
                    break;
            }

            if (Value > 10)
            {
                Points = 10;
            }
            else if (Value == 1) // If it's an ace
            {
                Points = 11; // Set the points to 11
            }
            else
            {
                Points = Value;
            }
        }
    }

    class Player
    {
        public PlayingCard[] hand;
        public int cardsInHand;
        public int points;
        public string name;

        public Player()
        {
            hand = new PlayingCard[5];
            cardsInHand = 0;
            points = 0;
        }

    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        onePlayer();

        Console.ReadLine();

    }

    // Generates the deck of 52 cards
    static PlayingCard[] generateDeck()
    {
        PlayingCard[] deck = new PlayingCard[52]; // Declares an array of PlayingCards with a size of 52
        int counter = 0; // Tells us where to save the next value into the array

        // Nested for loop to generate all 52 cards - 4 possible suits with 13 possible values each
        for (int suit = 1; suit < 5; suit++) // Loop through the 4 possible suits
        {
            for (int value = 1; value < 14; value++) // Loop through the 13 possible values
            {
                deck[counter] = new PlayingCard(suit, value); // Generate new card and store it in the deck
                counter++; // Increment the counter
            }
        }

        return deck; // Returns the completed deck
    }

    // Procedure to shuffle the deck of cards
    static void shuffleDeck(ref PlayingCard[] deck)
    {
        Random rnd = new Random(); // Creates new Random object
        PlayingCard temp; // Creates a variable for temporarily storing a PlayingCard
        int num; // Creates an integer variable for storing the randomly generated numbers

        for (int i = 0; i < deck.Length; i++) // Loop through each index in the array
        {
            num = rnd.Next(0, deck.Length); // Generate random num between 0 & 51

            // Swap the contents of deck[i] and deck[num]
            temp = deck[i];
            deck[i] = deck[num];
            deck[num] = temp;
        }

        // As deck is passed by reference, we do not need to return it to the main program
        // The changes will have automatically been applied to the deck in the main program
    }

    static void outputCard(PlayingCard card)
    {
        switch (card.Value) // Case statement based on the value of card
        {
            // Case for 1 - "The Ace of ..."
            case 1:
                Console.WriteLine("The Ace of {0}", card.Suit);
                break;

            // Case for 11 - "The Jack of ..."
            case 11:
                Console.WriteLine("The Jack of {0}", card.Suit);
                break;

            // Case for 12 - "The Queen of ..."
            case 12:
                Console.WriteLine("The Queen of {0}", card.Suit);
                break;

            // Case for 13 - "The King of ..."
            case 13:
                Console.WriteLine("The King of {0}", card.Suit);
                break;
            // Case for everything else 
            default:
                Console.WriteLine("The {0} of {1}", card.Value, card.Suit);
                break;
        }
    }

    // Output the details of a card using symbols - eg/ A♠
    // Used to output the player's hand on the same line (See outputHand procedure below)
    static void outputCardSymbol(PlayingCard card)
    {
        switch (card.Value) // Case statement based on the value of card
        {
            // Case for 1 - "The Ace of ..."
            case 1:
                Console.Write("A{0} ", card.Suit);
                break;

            // Case for 11 - "The Jack of ..."
            case 11:
                Console.Write("J{0} ", card.Suit);
                break;

            // Case for 12 - "The Queen of ..."
            case 12:
                Console.Write("Q{0} ", card.Suit);
                break;

            // Case for 13 - "The King of ..."
            case 13:
                Console.Write("K{0} ", card.Suit);
                break;
            // Case for everything else 
            default:
                Console.Write("{0}{1} ", card.Value, card.Suit);
                break;
        }
    }

    // Outputs all of the cards in a player's hand along with their point total
    static void outputHand(Player player)
    {
        // Print "Current Hand: "
        Console.Write("Current Hand: ");
        // Loop through all cards in hand
        for (int i = 0; i < player.cardsInHand; i++)
        {
            outputCardSymbol(player.hand[i]);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Current points: {0}.", player.points);
    }

    static void drawCard(PlayingCard[] deck, ref Player player)
    {
        PlayingCard nextCard = deck[pointer];

        // Add the next card in the deck to the player's hand
        if (player.cardsInHand <  5)
        {
            player.hand[player.cardsInHand] = nextCard;

            // Increment the number of cards in the player's hand
            player.cardsInHand++;

            // Add the point value of the new card to the player's total
            player.points += nextCard.Points;

            // Output the details of the card
            //outputCard(nextCard);

            // Increment the pointer
            pointer++;
        }
    }

    // Check if the player has exceeded 21 points
    // Output the player's point total
    static bool checkPoints(Player player)
    {
        // Output the player's point total
        //Console.WriteLine("Current Points: {0}", player.points);

        // Check if the player is bust
        if (player.points > 21)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Bust!");
            return false;
        }

        // Return true if the player is still alive
        return true;
    }

    // Compare the player & the dealer
    static void calculateWinner(Player player, Player dealer)
    {
        // Player wins if... 
        if (dealer.points > 21 || player.cardsInHand == 5 && dealer.cardsInHand != 5)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} Wins!", player.name);
        }

        // The game ends in a draw if... 
        else if (dealer.points == player.points)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Draw!");
        }
        // Otherwise, the dealer has won
        else if (dealer.points == 21 && player.points != 21 || player.cardsInHand < 5)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} wins", dealer.points);
        }
        else if (player.cardsInHand == 5 && dealer.cardsInHand == 5)
        {
            if (player.points > dealer.points)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} wins! 5 card trick: higher than dealers. ", player.name);
            }

            else if (player.points == dealer.points)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("It's a draw! 5 card trick: same! ");
            }

            Console.WriteLine("{0} wins! 5 card trick: less than dealers. ", dealer.name);
        }
    }

    // Checks if the player has any aces with a point value of 11 (high)
    // If the player is about to go bust, change the ace to a point value of 1 (low)
    // Then update the player's score
    static void checkAces(ref Player player)
    {
        bool changed = false; // Flags up if we've changed an ace already
        if (player.points > 21)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < player.cardsInHand; i++)
            {
                if (player.hand[i].Points == 11 && changed == false) // If it's a high ace
                {
                    player.hand[i].Points = 1; // Change it to a low ace
                    player.points -= 10; // Take 10 away from player's points
                    changed = true;
                }
            }
        }

    }

    static void onePlayer()
    {
        string playAgain = "Undefined";
        do
        {
            // Generate the deck of cards & shuffle it
            PlayingCard[] deck = generateDeck();
            shuffleDeck(ref deck);

            // Create the two player objects
            Player player = new Player();
            Console.Write("Please enter your name: ");
            player.name = Console.ReadLine();

            Player dealer = new Player();
            Console.Write("Please enter a name for the dealer: ");
            dealer.name = Console.ReadLine();

            // Draw the first two cards for the Player
            drawCard(deck, ref player);
            drawCard(deck, ref player);


            checkAces(ref player); // Call checkAces to see if we can stop player going bust
            outputHand(player);
            checkPoints(player); // Output the player's point total
            bool alive = true;

            string choice = "Undefined";

            while (alive == true && choice != "STICK")
            {
                Console.Write("Hit or Stick? ");
                choice = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();
                if (choice == "HIT") // If the user asks to hit then...
                {
                    drawCard(deck, ref player);

                    // If player still has a valid point total, alive will remain true
                    // If the player is now bust, alive will become false and the loop will exit
                    checkAces(ref player); // Call checkAces to see if we can stop player going bust
                    outputHand(player);
                    alive = checkPoints(player);
                }
            }
            // If the player isn't bust, it's time for the dealer's turn
            if (alive == true)
            {
                bool dealerAlive = true;

                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine("*** Dealer's Turn ***");
                drawCard(deck, ref dealer);
                drawCard(deck, ref dealer);

                checkAces(ref dealer); // Call checkAces to see if we can stop dealer going bust
                outputHand(dealer);
                checkPoints(dealer);

                while (dealerAlive == true)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to Continue");
                    Console.ReadLine();

                    // Draw the dealer's next card and check if they are still alive
                    drawCard(deck, ref dealer);

                    checkAces(ref dealer); // Call checkAces to see if we can stop dealer going bust
                    outputHand(dealer);
                    dealerAlive = checkPoints(dealer);
                }
            }

            // Calculate & output the winner
            calculateWinner(player, dealer);

            Console.Write("Do you want to play again? Y/N ");
            playAgain = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();
        } while (playAgain == "Y");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Is this your homework?

Comment: It's an extension task. My homework was to do the 5 card trick, so I wanted to do something trickier.

Answer (score 1):

Add each player to a `List<Player>` as this will keep each Player object to allow more than just two players as you can include the Dealer as a Player.

Also try to seperate your class rather than having multiple internal classes. It makes an easier read and makes navigation easier.

**Player.cs**

```
namespace Blackjack
{
    public class Player
    {
        public PlayingCard[] hand;
        public int cardsInHand;
        public int points;
        public string name;

        public Player()
        {
            hand = new PlayingCard[5];
            cardsInHand = 0;
            points = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Your game also has one slight problem, the dealer sticks from 17

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by separate my class? Cheers,

Comment: Add a new class in the project. Look at the updated answer. It will make each file smaller and to the point. The **Player** class will have all the properties the player should have.